# Django UNIQUE constraint

Tags: django, django-models, unique-constraint

Django UNIQUE constraint failed error

*`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed`* while I am using the unique together constraint in the models.

How can I use it properly?
While I am entering the data for the same publisher same issue same version number but different copy number I am getting the above error.
Is this the correct way to implement it??

```
class Book(models.Model):
    publisher = models.IntegerField()
    issue = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("publisher", "issue")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s-%r" % (self.publisher,self.issue)


class Version(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cover = models.ImageField(null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("book", "number")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.number, self.book)




class Copy(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    version = models.ForeignKey(Version, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    book_size = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=255)


    def __str__(self):
        return "%r" % (self.book_id)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("version", "number")
```

Comment: When did this error occured? While migrating?

Comment: While posting my data after executing the migration

Comment: It cause because duplicate data already exist in your database!!!

Comment: I have removed the data and tried. The thing is I am having three different models and the unique together relationships are constructed across the the three tables. Is it possible to implement that?

Comment: Post some more code. Your model structure etc

Comment: posted the model structure, thanks in advance..

Comment: It seems like your database still contains data. Double check whether it empty or not. Can you post the input data you tried to post